# PHP: htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to apply the htmlspecialchars to the script below, but all attempts have just resulted in error messages. I believe it should be something like: echo htmlspecialchars($lines), but not sure how this would apply to the code below, or if I should use something else.

The end result should convert the text from the .txt file from :
Anna said she \"wouldn\'t go to Hannah\'s house\".

to:
Anna said she "wouldn't go to Hannah's house".

```
<?php
$lines = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
uasort($lines, 'strnatcasecmp');

foreach ($lines as $num => $line) { 
printf("%s (line #%d)<br>", $line, $num);
}
?>
```

Comment: where do you call the htmlspecialchars function ?

Comment: You are not going to learn programming by randomly editing code and asking people for pastes. Take a moment to understand the error message and fix it. *Ask about that if you cannot figure it out* individually. Repeat.

Comment: also htmlspecialchars doesn't unescape quotes. it converts html chars to coresponding entities: & => &amp;

Comment: I just noticed that "end result" thing. `htmlspecialchars` has nothing to do with quotes... :/

Comment: "htmlspecialchars has nothing to do with quotes" ok, thanks I see that now which is why I was getting confused. the tutorial I was going through was wrong then. No great surprise there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$lines = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
uasort($lines, 'strnatcasecmp');

foreach ($lines as $num => $line) { 
$line = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($line), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
printf("%s (line #%d)<br>", $line, $num);
}
?>
```

`stripslashes()` will remove the slashes from that content for you.

Even though `htmlspecialchars()` won't deal with the slashes I included them since it's good form to use it on user generated data (I'm assuming what is in the text file user generated data).

Answer (score 0):

Try stripslashes()

```
<?php
$lines = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
uasort($lines, 'strnatcasecmp');

foreach ($lines as $num => $line) { 
printf("%s (line #%d)<br>", stripslashes($line), $num);
}
?>
```

Comment: I really don't want to know how you came up with this answer within 30 seconds of the question being posted.

Comment: the question was:

The end result should convert the text from the .txt file from : Anna said she \"wouldn\'t go to Hannah\'s house\".

to: Anna said she "wouldn't go to Hannah's house".

Stripslashes() does that

Comment: My issue with this answer is that it doesn't teach the OP anything even while the question is *a wild shot in the dark*. A bare "Try stripslashes" will only encourage *more* questions like that. Since you took the time to answer, please take the time to answer *well*.

Comment: Im genuinely interested... why to people sometimes mark questions down, and then not explain why. As someone new to all this, I've had questions marked up and down, and they're all written fairly similarly with a similar amount of time researched before asking. How should I be asking, or what should I do to make it easier/better for people answering my questions.

Comment: To my opinion you did a great job. You stated the question, and clearly defined what you expected as a result. On top of that, you added additional info. I agree with Jon, that providing clear info educates others. In this case, not too much time had to be spent as the answer to get you on track was pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
    $lines = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    uasort($lines, 'strnatcasecmp');

    foreach ($lines as $num => $line) { 
        echo htmlspecialchars("$line (line #$num)<br>");
    }
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this changes the other parts of the formatting which I also needed. I can see in the answer below where I went wrong. thanks anyway.